# I want to my discord bot to forward the message to another channel after a user reacts to it Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I know next to nothing about coding in Python but I created this bot from tutorials I found online and it does little things in my private server.

One thing we'd love to do is to react to certain messages so they will be collected in a specific channel. I've seen a few servers do this, like a highlights kind of thing.

I found something [promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62766934/how-to-make-bot-send-message-to-another-channel-after-reaction-discord-js) here in Stackoverflow but it's in javascript :<

Edit: 2023-01-19 08:53 GMT+8

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, member):
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "⭐":
            channel = await bot.get_channel(channel_id)
            await channel.send(reaction.message.content)
```

Final code
edited: 2023-01-20 17:14 GMT+8

```py
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.emoji == "⭐":
        astrometrics = bot.get_channel(channel id here)
        embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xFEE75C)
        embed.set_author(name = reaction.message.author.name, icon_url = reaction.message.author.display_avatar)
        embed.add_field(name = "Message Content", value = reaction.message.content)
        if len(reaction.message.attachments) > 0:
            embed.set_image(url = reaction.message.attachments[0].url)
        embed.add_field(name = "Go to message", value = reaction.message.jump_url, inline = False)
        await astrometrics.send(embed = embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check certain messages in `on_message` [event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message). And for getting a specific channel in your server, you need to have the channel id. [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel)
Something like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'the certain message':
        specific_channel = await bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        await specific_channel.send(message.content)
```

But this might have some rate-limited consequence if the 'certain message' was too much and sent at a high rate. (If yes, then there's nothing you can do since rate-limited is a discord limitation).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response and the resources! I came up with this based on what I read but it doesn't work and I'm not even sure if it makes sense (added to the post)

Comment: you need to have a valid channel_id in order to get that channel. Also, if you have one and it is still not working, send the error

Comment: Hello! I have a channel id, that's just for placeholder. I was getting an error re: inconsistency with tabs and spaces. So I typed it manually again. It's working now. I also reverted to your initial suggestion and just used bot (not client), i understand now that i can just have the bot and it will do everything a client does. I also played around with the embed. Attaching the final code. Thank you so much for the help!